# For loop in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms

I have an Oracle Forms project.
The project go like this.

I have a database that has a table with the name `students_payment`.
The form just has two blocks.

First block called `date_1` contains from_date and to_date
When you put a date like 14-3-2019  to 14-3-2020
and press enter
the second block called `details_1`. It's tabular and will have three display items:

1. student nationality
2. paid
3. non_paid

It will fill the tabular like this

```
Nationality       USA  

paid        65  

Non_paid    36
```

That mean USA students who paid their university study fees are 65 and who didn't pay are 36,

I did all of this but the problem that I put my code without WHERE condition for the nationality so it will bring all nationalities. But it brings just the first record that is USA.

How can I put a select statement in a FOR LOOP to put the first country in the first record, and the second country on the second record, and so on for all the nationalities??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying one thing and displaying another, and these two don't match.

If second block is *tabular*, then its layout should look like

```
Nationality    Paid    Non-paid
-----------    ----    --------
USA              65          35
France           70          30
```

i.e. not the way you have it; your layout is *form*, not *tabular*. I suggest you delete that block and create it from scratch, but this time paying attention to what Wizard asks.

It will also solve problem you currently have; *form* layout displays one record at a time. *Tabular* layout displays several records.

As far as I understood, there's no relationship between those two blocks. Values used in the first one are used to restrict rows returned in the second block. Therefore, the second block must be database block, based on a table (don't make it *control block*, if that's what you have now). Doing so, even if there's nothing in the first block, when you're positioned in the second block and *execute query*, you'd get all rows stored in that table. Forms do that automatically, you don't have to write a single line of code.

`FOR` loop you mentioned? In my opinion, you should avoid it. It is almost always *wrong* choice in a database block, but can be used in a control block. But, why bother? Let Forms do the dirty job.

Now, back to result restriction: you could use a `PRE-BLOCK` trigger on the second block and use `SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY` built-in & its `ONETIME_WHERE` property, using date items from the first block, e.g.

```
set_block_property('second_block', 
                    onetime_where, 
                   'date_column between :first_block.date_from and :second_block.date_to');
```

Or, use second block's Property Palette and set the `WHERE` clause to

```
where date_column between :first_block.date_from and :second_block.date_to
```

Comment: I know what you mean about the problem is when I put my code it just show me the first record usa students then the second column there is nothing that's why I need a for loop right?

Comment: No; most probably **wrong**. If it is a database block, then Forms will return all rows that satisfy conditions. Your only condition regards dates. It means that only the USA satisfies the condition and only that row is returned. Test it in SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer or TOAD or whichever tool you use).